# Does NancyFX have an equivalent to HttpRequest.ServerVariables holding X-Forwarded-For values?

Tags: c#, nancy

I'd like to determine whether there is an X_FORWARDED_FOR value on the request made to my NancyFX handler. In MVC, this is held in the ServerVariables named collection of the HttpRequest.

Where should I look to find the same value in NancyFX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All HTTP request headers are available in your module via the `Request` property on `NancyModule`.
E.g.:

```
public class MyModule : NancyModule
{
  public MyModule()
  {
    Get["/"] =_ => 
      Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"].Any() ? HttpStatusCode.OK :
                                                 HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
  }
}
```

Comment: That ended up being what I did, but I did want to check that it was the correct way to use NancyFX. Thanks!